# Testing for a specific nested tuple structure

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

In a part of my code, I got an argument being passed in form of `((int, int), (int, int))`, for example: `((1, 2), (3, 4))`. I need a fast test that checks if the passed argument is exactly in that form. Something along the lines of:

```py
>>> foo = ((1, 2), (3, 4))
>>> bar = ((1, 'not int'), (3, 4))
>>> buz = (1, 2, 3)
>>> test(foo)
    True
>>> test(bar)
    False
>>> test(buz)
    False
```

Somewhat naively, I've tried this:

```py
>>> isinstance(((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((int, int), (int, int)) 
    False
```

but that didn't work that well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Imagine if it did though